# meaning of "stuck up"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*You're so **stuck up on the verdict**. It's frustrating to reply to you because none of your points address what I'm saying. Forget the jury's ruling. Look deeper into it than its surface. I did misrepresent your argument though. I apologize.*

It is a quote from an internet discussion. It concerns the verdict in the trial. Can you tell me what the meaning of "so stuck up" could be in the context. I know that pharse "stuck-up" means snobbish but in my sentence it does not fit. I would interpret it as "You are so blindly confirmed that the verdict was OK". But not sure.

Comment: The sentence doesn't imply that "you" (whoever that is...) agrees with the verdict or not. "You" is simply fixated on the verdict. The implication is that "you" is only considering the verdict and ignoring the other points that the writer of the comment is trying to make.

Comment: Using *hung up* instead of *stuck up* might make more sense. As you said, the example is not the usual usage of *stuck up*.

Comment: I concur with @user3169. It's possible in some contexts to say "you're **stuck** on X" with more or less the same sense as "you're **hung up** on X", and I suspect that the writer just suffered a mental burp in the process of writing.

Comment: I also don't recognise this use of _stuck up_.